# Custom memo field isn't copied to Reply or Forward in Lotus Notes 6.5

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I work in a development/support team which has a shared Lotus Notes mailbox. We need to be able to associate an issue ID with each email. We started by adding this ID to the subject line (eg. "Something doesn't work [ID12345]"). For performance reasons, our IT dept don't allow indexing of shared mailboxes, so it takes a long time to search for a particular ID.

I decided to add a new ID field, which can be shown as a sortable column in views and folders. I put this field to the visible header (just below 'Subject') in the ($All) view and the ($Inbox) folder, and copied the ($Inbox) design to all the other folders in the database. That much was easy.

My problem is that when we reply or forward, this custom field is not carried over to the new memo, so we have to manually add it again before sending. And of course when the user responds, the field is again missing and must be manually added. I have searched the docs and the internet and haven't found any information on this. Either I have to declare this field as something which persists across replies and forwards, or I have to add a line somewhere which explicitly copies the field contents to the new memo.

Comment: Have you considered just taking a local replica of the mail file and working from that?  You can build the full text index locally, so your IT department's (bad!) policy wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

fsw,
   We do exactly this with our complaint system however our database is indexed although this should not be an issue to you. We created a view that is sorted by ID by extracting just the ID from the subject line, order it by ID and then by date descending. Base it on the $ALL folder view so you get both incoming and sent emails.

We then altered the memo form to include an embedded view single category of the new view that sits above the body which shows all other documents linked to the ticket.

This should avoid having to delve to far into the very complex mail template any further. One thing is to make sure you have a copy of the changes you made and a bit of doco re deploying as you can guarantee that one day your template will be completely overwritten in an upgrade and all your good work will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

As the additional field would have to incorporated into all Memo forms in mail templates in your corporation and as these fields do not easily travel via SMTP, you should stick with the ID in the subject.

What you could do is to parse the subject (@Mid, @Right, ...) in the column formula in the view and only display the ID there (like you did with the additional field).

Comment: Also to the Reply form, and I'm not so sure anything can be done about forwarding -- at least from perspective of the built-in forwarding feature in the client.

Answer (score 0):

The other option I envision if having a field is required is to have an agent that processes the incoming message(reply) to have it parse out the issue ID from the subject and write it to the field. You could also do that with queryopen or postopen if running an agent is not possible